# How do I do a fluid splash in blender

Tags: fluid-simulation

I tried to make a splash with fluid following a tutorial but something went wrong and I cant figure it out.  Heres what its doing on the video link.  How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: This is a link to the place on your physical volume (computer). We cannot access it. Please add some screenshots and be more descriptive.

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't know how to add a video.

Comment: There is no option to add video here. This is why you will need to add screenshots and describe your issue in detail.

Comment: Ok I'll fix this.

Comment: I made it a gif, so I can show the problem

Comment: In the [fluid world properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/domain.html#fluid-world) what is the real world size? The default is 0.5 meters.

Comment: Apply scale to the objects, this should help.

Comment: The real world size is on 0.5

Comment: What do you mean by apply scale to objects

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html - Apply paragraph.

Comment: I feel like a broken record here.. but please use this website to let us see your file and test to see if the error occurs on our side. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/